# Does XをYと感じる　here mean to feel X to be Y?

Tags: syntax

I am not confident I parsed this correctly (text from Mishima's Patriotism). Please confirm or deny:

> 中尉は麗子が「お供をする」と言った言葉を、新婚の夜から、自分が麗子を導いて、このばに及んで、それを澱みなく発音させたという大きな教育の成果と感じた。

Can this be summed up as 中尉はA言葉を、B成果と感じた。, as in the lieutenant **felt** the words (described by A) to be the **product** (of his "education", described by B). (I am not not looking for translation, but rather for whether I understood the underlying syntax correctly).

Thank you.

Comment: You sure it says 「お供にする」?  To me, that should be 「を」 or else it makes no sense.

Comment: You're right, my typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct on this.

「新婚の夜から、自分が麗子を導いて、このばに及んで、それを澱みなく発音させたという大きな教育の成果」 is one big relative clause where everything else eventually modifies 「成果」.

The narrator is saying that the lieutenant feels Reiko's statement to be his huge 「成果」.